# MVC + Razor: how to add starting <div> conditionally?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I want to amend a div based on whether a variable is set or not.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
@if (SomethingIsSet) {

<div style="background:red">

} else {

<div style="background:blue"> }
```

But I get the following error message in Visual Studio:

> The div element was not closed. All elements must be either
>   self-closing or have a matchig end tag.

My div element is closed later on in the page.

Comment: Ignore the message.

Comment: I agree, I think you can ignore it. The final HTML will still be correct, which is all that matters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator in Razor.

```
<div style="@(SomethingIsSet ? "background:red" : "background:blue")">
```

Comment: That works; the disadvantage is that you lose intellisense for the CSS.

Comment: @GSerg, that's true. But when I do this I usually know the classes that I want to use in the first place.