# Set bootstrap column width conditionally?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I have the following html in a cshtml file in our episerver project:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8">
```

If there is no background image selected then I want to change those values to be full width.

This is what I have been trying to do, but it is causing a exception fault:

```
<div class="@(!ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CurrentBlock.Image) ? col-sm-7 col-md-8 : col-sm-12 col-md-12)">
```

I am hoping it boils down to a syntax issue I am not familiar with as a newbie?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200313/5836671), you need to wrap the strings with quotation marks: `? "col-sm-7 col-md-8" : "col-sm-12 col-md-12"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression isn't returning `strings`.

It should be:

```
<div class="@(!ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CurrentBlock.Image) ? "col-sm-7 col-md-8" : "col-sm-12 col-md-12")">
```